# How can I speed a double for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have the following R code. The function Heaviside2 is the Heaviside step function, while the matrix A is a matrix of data.

```
for (i in 1:N){
   for (j in 1:N){
      if (j!=i) {
          arg=r-normvec(A[i,]-A[j,])
          s=s+Heaviside2(arg)
      }
   }
}
```

I try to speed this code, deleting the double for, but the inner "if" makes it more difficult.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data using `dput` function?

Comment: You could restructure the double loop as `for (i in 1:N-1)` and `for (j in i:N)`, but you would still need to evaulate `normvec()` twice.  Perhaps if you only needed to compute it once, then this option would give you a factor of 2 speed increase.

Comment: Are you sure the for loops play any role at all in the speed? I kind of think it would be dominated by the N^2 `normvec` calls.

Comment: normvec(x-y) == normvec(y-x), right? That would give you a factor of two.

Comment: @MikeWise, Yes normvec(x-y) == normvec(y-x).

Comment: Thank you, I try to follow your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `dist` function is very helpful. So I think the solution would be

```
sum(Heaviside(r - dist(A)))
```

I don't know what Heaviside function are you using, but I'm using the one from `fBasics` package.